# Pass google default application credentials in local docker run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-sdk

Is there a way of passing my local google default application credentials (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) via docker run?

My usecase:

- Code running locally on my machine correctly handles default application credentials
- Code running within docker image on the GCE instance also correctly handles the default application credentials
- The problem is with "docker run" on my machine. Code running in the docker container do not use host default application credentials.

It would be nice if I could tell "docker run" to pass the host google default application credentials to the docker image.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Passing `-v ~/.config:/root/.config` should make it work.  This assumes that your local code uses application default credentials stored by `gcloud auth login` in ~/.config/gcloud and that the user's home directory in the container is /root.

Comment: Works, thanks. For people reading this - you may not need the whole .config, as there are many more configs not related to gcloud there.

Comment: @kozikow is right, ~/.config/gcloud will suffice. I document how to do this on Windows & Linux in this new blog post here: http://blog.ctaggart.com/2016/11/pass-google-application-default.html

Comment: Do `unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` if you have this variable set. That would be if you were using service account credentials json before, like I was