# Use google default credentials on local docker run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-sdk

I have the same problem asked on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938216/pass-google-default-application-credentials-in-local-docker-run), but the provided solution does not work for me.

Basically, I want to run my docker image, with entrypoint `run_query.py`, locally. I have issues with credentials when I try to run a Bigquery job.

When I try to run my
docker run -v ~/.config/:/root/.config my-image-name --param1 ...

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_query.py", line 97, in <module>
  query_params=params)
File "run_query.py", line 54, in create_table
  query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 2467, in query
  query_job._begin(retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 3156, in _begin
  super(QueryJob, self)._begin(client=client, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 638, in _begin
  retry, method="POST", path=path, data=self.to_api_repr(), timeout=timeout
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 558, in _call_api
  return call()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
  on_error=on_error,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
  return target()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 419, in api_request
  timeout=timeout,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 277, in _make_request
  method, url, headers, data, target_object, timeout=timeout
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 315, in _do_request
  url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 444, in request
  self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
  self.refresh(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 198, in refresh
  self._scopes,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 248, in refresh_grant
  response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 124, in _token_endpoint_request
  _handle_error_response(response_body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
  raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
```

I also tried to use `-v ~/.config/gcloud/:/root/.config/gcloud`, but I get the same result.

Keep in mind that using this image into a Kubeflow Pipeline works smoothly.

Did I misinterpret the solution from the previous question? What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of the BigQuery dependency do you use?

Comment: I'm using `google/cloud-sdk:slim` Docker image as base, then installing `google-cloud-bigquery` without specifying a version, so I suppose it uses the latest (1.26.1?).

Comment: Do you not perform a `pip install` to download some dependencies?

Comment: My Dockerfile starts with `FROM google/cloud-sdk:slim 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`

Comment: May you provide your docker file?

Comment: From the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938216/pass-google-default-application-credentials-in-local-docker-run?noredirect=1&lq=1) I'm assuming your script runs correctly locally and this only happens when you try using the Docker image, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the case!