# Google Application Default Credentials during local docker build

Tags: docker, google-artifact-registry

I have a Docker image of a javascript application that uses private npm packages stored in Google's Artifact Registry.

Inside Google's CloudBuild I can specify `docker build -t myimage --network=cloudbuild .` and inside the docker build I can run `npx google-artifactregistry-auth` which retrieves the credentials using the build service account and then I can run my `RUN npm install`.

However, locally when I have ADC on my computer (macOS), setup by running `gcloud auth application-default login`, running the same command in docker fails saying:

> #19 2.583 npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: google-artifactregistry-auth@3.1.1
> #19 6.822 Retrieving application default credentials...
> #19 6.846 Retrieving credentials from gcloud...
> #19 6.856 Error: Fail to get credentials. Please run: 
> #19 6.856 `gcloud auth application-default login`, `gcloud auth login`, or 
> #19 6.856 `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path/to/service/account/key>`
> #19 6.856     at Object.getCreds (/root/.npm/_npx/64aef35f3ba01c7c/node_modules/google-artifactregistry-auth/src/auth.js:40:9)
> #19 6.856     at async main (/root/.npm/_npx/64aef35f3ba01c7c/node_modules/google-artifactregistry-auth/src/main.js:83:19)

I tried setting the environment variable to my local path to no avail:

```
docker build --build-arg GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/myname_here/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json -t hello_world .
```

Comment: the environment variable points to a file that should be available in the docker image during the build process. Since you're not copying it, it won't work. If this is for testing purposes, I suggest to add a COPY in the Dockerfile.

Comment: @Stefano this is not for `testing purposes`. I want to have a single Dockerfile that works both for Cloud Build and for my local docker such that it uses appropriate creds in each context.

Comment: can you check this github [thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-npm-tools/issues/49#issuecomment-1485815578)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya thanks for that, unfortunately there is no resolution there for me :(

Comment: @SathiAiswarya unfortunately it is not because I want the same Dockerfile on my local and in CloudBuild, installing gcloud blows it up and I don't want to bundle gcloud with my application in production.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you have a look at it once.

Answer (score 1):

The `application_default_credentials.json` created by gcloud application-default login cannot be used as the service account json key.It will be  referenced by the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` because they have different contents.

As mentioned in this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938216/pass-google-default-application-credentials-in-local-docker-run)   you can do

> mount `~/.config` of your machine to `/root/.config` inside the container,
> and make sure your docker image has gcloud installed. The
> `application_default_credentials.json` created by gcloud is only
> understandable by gcloud, so you will need to expose that to the
> docker container and let the gcloud inside the docker container do the
> authentication.

If the above steps does not help you  Sometimes errors may arise with the `npx google-artifactregistry-auth` command which requires a gcloud credential. Please note that  `google-artifactregistry-auth` module is an npm package which allows you to configure npm to interact with npm private repositories in Artifact Registry. Therefore, I would request you to please follow the steps mentioned in the below.

1. Login using  commands
   - `$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[path/to/key.json]` or `$ gcloud auth application-default login`
2. Add settings to connect to the repository to .npmrc. Use the output from the following command:

   `$ gcloud artifacts print-settings npm`
3. Run the module outside of the directory containing the target npmrc file

`$ npx google-artifactregistry-auth --repo-config=[./.npmrc] --credential-config=[~/.npmrc]`

4. Also, Include the command[1]  in the scripts in package.json
5. Run the Script using $ npm run artifactregistry-login

Also, Please refer to the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-artifactregistry-auth) which explains more details about the above mentioned steps.

[1] "scripts": {    "artifactregistry-login": "npx google-artifactregistry-auth --repo-config=[./.npmrc] --credential-config=[~/.npmrc]",}

Comment: This does not work during Docker Build unless I install gcloud CLI FOR the build and then I am doing the same inside cloud build where it works without it. how do I make my own computer behave the same way as CloudBuild where this is NOT REQUIRED.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [the official documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/authentication). This gives the step-by-step directions for setting it up.

Make sure the `.npmrc` file content is updated with the correct settings.

Comment: I already followed the steps, mate. It works fine in my local. It ONLY works in docker if I copy token to the .npmrc file which makes it contain credentials and IS NOT what I want.

Comment: This seems to be an expected behavior, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/authentication#:~:text=Storing%20the%20token%20in%20your%20user%20.npmrc%20file%20isolates%20your%20credentials%20from%20your%20source%20code%20and%20your%20source%20control%20system.). In local, the credentials are stored under  "~/. config/gcloud"

Comment: Exactly. So how does Cloud Build do it if I do not need to put my credentials into .npmrc but it still works?
How does Google Cloud Shell do it?Because it also works in cloud shell albeit with an interactive prompt.

I want to replicate either in my local docker.

Comment: If you remove "~/.config/gcloud", it will stop working in Cloud Shell/local.

Comment: How does that information help me?